# Angular 5 components not displaying for child routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-router

I have a series of nested components

Main app component -> products-> product groups

app-routing module routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: environment.devRedirect,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'customers/:customerId/contracts/:contractId',
    loadChildren: './products/products-routing.module#ProductsRoutingModule',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    data: {
      breadcrumb: null,
      animation: 'products'
    }
  }
];
```

My products routes looks like

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsOverviewComponent,
    data: {
      animation: 'overview',
      breadcrumb: 'Products',
    },
    canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'products/:productId/grouping',
        loadChildren: '../grouping/grouping-routing.module#GroupingRoutingModule',
        data: {
          breadcrumb: null,
          animation: 'grouping'
        },
        canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ]
      },
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: ProductsComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Create',
          animation: 'create'
        },
        canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ]
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:productId',
        component: QuoteOptionComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Edit',
          animation: 'edit' },
        canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And then in my product grouping module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OverviewComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ],
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Grouping',
      animation: 'grouping-overview',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'create',
        component: CreateEditComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Create',
          animation: 'group-create'
        },
        canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ]
      },
      {
        path: ':groupId/edit',
        component: CreateEditComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Edit Group Info',
          animation: 'group-edit'
        },
        canActivate: [ AuthenticationGuard ]

    ]
  }
];
```

All my routerlinks work and the url path updates and any data inside the router is pulled back for each route. My problem is that the component for each of the routes is never displayed. Am I missing something here or how do I get the components to display in the main router outlet?

Comment: Do you have  `<router-outlet>`s in both `ProductsOverviewComponent` and `OverviewComponent`?

Comment: No I assumed that if no child router outlets present it would use the primary

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Comment: Is there any way to get a nested route structure like mine but use the main router outlet? I need the nested structure for the breadcrumbs but I need it to use the main router outlet. I've tried specifying the outlet in the route config but no luck

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, `children` property must be combined with nested `<router-outlet>`.

Comment: You need the router-outlet tag in the component html, because the router-outlet is the **placeholder** for the child route component, what you can do for your breadcrumb is to inject the router into the parent and listen for route changes.